# htaccess rules not routing properly on server (real file check)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, routes

Man.. I'm at a loss. I have a basic rewrite flow that I can't seem to get working. I want to check if a real-file exists. If it does, serve it, but if it doesn't, reroute to a PHP file. Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ core/index.php?f=%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

RewriteRule (.*) application/$1 [L]
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
.
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  application
│   └── [-rw-r--r--]  test.html
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  core
│   ├── [-rw-r--r--]  index.php
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x]  tmp
│       ├── [-rw-r--r--]  httpd-access.log
│       ├── [-rw-r--r--]  httpd-error.log
│       └── [-rw-r--r--]  rewrite.log
└── [-rw-r--r--]  .htaccess

3 directories, 6 files
```

Here are the permission
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: 1) Please provide an URL example 2) Please explain the logic of what are you trying to achieve (using URL from #1) 3) What results do you have right now and what result do you expect instead? I'm asking because I think you may have an rewrite loop here.

Comment: 1) i dont have this available online right now. 2) im trying to serve real files located in the application directory via website.com/realfile.txt, and have all other requests (eg. not real files) routed to a php file. 3) real files are routed to the php file.

Comment: I'm not asking about real online URL -- I just need an example URL, like `http://example.com/meow` (using your own files/urls)

Comment: the real file, for example, is local.web.com/test.html and test.html is in the application directory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Apache has mod rewrite turned on?

Comment: yup. changing the final rule to something like RewriteRule (.*) http://www.google.com?f=$1 [L] works. It seems the rule's are being captured properly, but sub-requests are causing issues?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add **RewriteBase /** or **RewriteBase %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}** directive right after **RewriteEngine On**

Comment: RewriteBase %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} doesn't seem to be allowed, and RewriteBase / didn't seem to help. It's the secondary routing after it meets the last rule with the L flag that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To be placed in **.htaccess** in root folder. If you going to place in in config file (inside `<VirtualHost>` for example) then it needs to be slightly modified.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# 1) do not do anything for existing file or folder
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# 2) real file (in application folder) -- rewrite path
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule (.*) /application/$1 [L]
# 3) nope, no such file -- serve via index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /core/index.php?f=%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

The important thing that many people forgetting about, is the fact that after URL was rewritten it goes to next iteration. And on such next iteration URL is already different to the originally requested. These rules should take care about this moment.

This is how it will work for `/test.html`:

1. Rule #1 will be skipped as there is no `/test.html`
2. Rule #2 will work, as there is a file `/application/test.html`. Rewrite goes to next iteration (`[L]` flag).
3. Rule #1 will work as URL now is `/application/test.html` and such file does exist. This rule tells Apache to stop rewriting any further -- job done.

This is how it will work for `/meow.html`:

1. Rule #1 will be skipped as there is no `/meow.html`
2. Rule #2 will be skipped as there is no file `/application/meow.html`.
3. Rule #3 will work -- URL rewritten to `core/index.php?f=%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/meow.html`.  Rewrite goes to next iteration (`[L]` flag).
4. Rule #1 will work as URL now is `/core/index.php` and such file does exist. This rule tells Apache to stop rewriting any further -- job done.

**EDIT:**
You may add leading slash `/` before destination part of RewriteRule (should be no difference ... but your setup could be a bit different from mine).

Comment: heya. i tried that one out, and while it worked, it allowed /application/test.html to be routed. this isn't ideal as it in a way exposes the file system/structure. i tried to comment out the first 2 conditions and rules, but that would then break the re-routing of /application/test.html. any thoughts?

Comment: @onassar What do you mean by _"it allowed /application/test.html to be routed"_? **Please explain**. I've tested these rules few times locally before posting an answer -- it works perfectly here: all redirects are internal so URL stays the same in the browser. If you have your URL changed in browser's address bar -- you may have it cached from previous attempts or something -- try another browser or clear caches and restart. Did you put all rules as is .. or you have mixed them with your own -- show your current .htaccess. P.S. -- What's your Apache version? I have 2.2.17

Comment: im running 2.2.16 apache. when i copy and paste your rules exactly the same, it allows the request (on the same domain) /application/test.html to be served which isn't ideal. thoughts? they work as you've described, but im hoping to find a solution that prevents exposing the directory structure of the site.

Comment: @onassar Sorry, but you are **still unclear** with this "/application/test.html" issue. I have to guess ... that you do not want to have direct request to be allowed (e.g. `http://www.example.com/application/test.html`). IF so -- add `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$` into rule #1 (see updated answer). Keep in mind, that such request will be served via `core/index.php?f=%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/application/test.html` (as you can see the path will be wrong as we rejecting the original request forcing it to be served via core/index.php where extra `/application` part is added).

Comment: You should also note that this _may not work_ -- depends on your Apache's configuration (although I think it will work)

Comment: Hey LazyOne, this did not work. You described it the way I would like it to work (eg. it should be routed to core/index.php?f=%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/application/test.html), but it doesn't seem to do the job. Thoughts?

Comment: Well .. the code works for sure on my setup exactly as I have described. If for whatever reason it does not work, then if you can edit Apache config file, enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLoglevel 9`) and check rewrite log for details. I cannot debug code on **your server** from overhere -- your Apache may be configured differently. If it's shared hosting, then try installing Apache/PHP/etc on your own PC and debug it there.

Comment: As I understand, this `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` variable is not get updated by Apache .. and I don't really know another way of detecting if it is a direct request (1st iteration) or 2nd/3rd/Nth rewrite iteration.

Comment: I know apache 2.3 has END flag, but not in 2.2.x. I am running on my own slice. No shared server. No worries man. Thanks for your help. I tried running rewrite logging but I find it obtuse to process.